# Adb devices can't find Android device on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: android, macos, adb

I'm struggling here to debug my app on my phone.

I'm new to the Mac world, and I used to develop on Windows with no problems, so I guess it's not a problem of my phone...

To make it clear, this is my issue right now

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
(empty)
```

I have tried the following:

- Enable USB debugging on my phone
- Modify the adb_usb.ini file to include the Vendor ID
- Set the connection mode to "USB massive storage"
- adb kill-server / adb start-server / adb devices ...
- reboot the computer
- reboot the phone
- yell at the computer

Nothing seems to work... What else, I haven't installed EasyTether or anything like that, so it shouldn't interfere. My phone is a ZTE Skate, I mention it because it is not so famous, but as I said before, I could work with it on Windows...

As a curious fact, when plugging the phone on Windows, the notification bar showed something like "Debugging unit connected", but this doesn't appear when I connect it to the Mac. And of course, in both cases I have the "USB debugging" option activated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well if you read the Google documentation then "If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works." This isn't always the case though.  Try using a powered USB hub to connect the phone. That was the only way I could get a Macbook to recognize my Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I think I found a workaround. Looks like an awkward solution, but as long as it works...
I tried to use the wifi adb applications, such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50dHhhcHBzLndpZmlhZGIiXQ.. as an alternative. The problem is, that these apps require a rooted device. Anyway, the sole app start (without turning on the feature) made my device to be aware of being a debugging unit. Then, I just connected the USB cable and it worked as usual. Hope this helps someone! Of course, if anyone finds a cleaner solution, just post it!

Comment: I guess you always have the option to root your device and use the application as intended